# How to Choose default startup kernel ubuntu 12.04 with a GUI program

Tags: kernel, gui, default

Is there any Gui program like the old startup-manager to control the default boot kernel behaviour in ubuntu 12.04?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Grub Customizer will do what you want.  It's available through a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```